# How can I transpose and parse a large vertical text file into a CSV file with headers?

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting

I have a large text file (*.txt) in the following format:

```
; KEY 123456
; Any Company LLC
; 123 Main St, Anytown, USA

SEC1 = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SEC2 = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SEC3 = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SEC4 = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SEC5 = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SEC6 = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

This is repeated for about 350 - 400 keys. These are HASP keys and the SEC codes associated with them. I am trying to parse this file into a CSV file with KEY and SEC1 - SEC6 as the headers, with the rows being filled in. This is the format I am trying to get to:

```
KEY,SEC1,SEC2,SEC3,SEC4,SEC5,SEC6
123456,xxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxx
456789,xxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxx
```

I have been able to get a script to export to a CSV with only one key in the text file (my test file), but when I try to run it on the full list, it only exports the last key and sec codes.

```
$keysheet = '.\AllKeys.txt'
$holdarr = @{}

Get-Content $keysheet | ForEach-Object {
if ($_ -match "KEY") {
    $key, $value = $_.TrimStart("; ") -split " "
    $holdarr[$key] = $value }
elseif ($_ -match "SEC") {
    $key, $value = $_ -split " = "
    $holdarr[$key] = $value }
}

$hash = New-Object PSObject -Property $holdarr
$hash | Export-Csv -Path '.\allsec.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

When I run it on the full list, it also adds a couple of extra columns with what looks like properties instead of values.

Any help to get this to work would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out the `ConvertFrom-StringData` cmdlet.  It will make your life WAY easier when trying to parse `Key=Value` pairs.

Comment: Is there always a group of exactly 6 sec lines?

Comment: @Matt Yes. There are always exactly 6 SEC lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be one approach.

```
& {
    $entry = $null
    switch -Regex -File '.\AllKeys.txt' {
        "KEY" {
            if ($entry ) {
                [PSCustomObject]$entry
            }
            $entry = @{}
            $key, $value = $_.TrimStart("; ") -split " "
            $entry[$key] = [int]$value
        }
         "SEC" {
            $key, $value = $_ -split " = "
            $entry[$key] = $value 
        }
    }
    [PSCustomObject]$entry
} | sort KEY | select KEY,SEC1,SEC2,SEC3,SEC4,SEC5,SEC6 |
Export-Csv -Path '.\allsec.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Your `$entry=$null` at the head is unnecessary (unless it's defined outside of the scriptblock, but then I'd argue use `$local:` or `$private:` modifiers)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 The language might not require it, but I think it's still good style to add it.

Comment: @marsze This is close. The header row is exporting, but all other rows are empty, with just the delimiter.

Comment: @Harlan I have made some edits. Did you use the latest version? Also, try to check the output before exporting. See where exactly empty values are returned. I tested this with your data and it should work fine.

Comment: @marsze It depended on the version of PS that I was using. Initially I was using 2.0. When I tried it on a machine that had PS 5, it worked like a charm. The only change was that I had to get rid of the [int] that was casting the KEY value. Not sure why though. The error was that it couldn't convert from `System.Object[]` to `System.Int32`. Thanks!

Comment: @Harlan I suppose there were spaces in they `KEY` value then (?) Anyways, the int-cast was only for sorting, not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the approach I suggest:

```
$output = switch -Regex -File './AllKeys.txt' {
    '^; KEY (?<key>\d+)' {
        if ($o) {
            [pscustomobject]$o
        }
        $o = @{
            KEY = $Matches['key']
        }
    }

    '^(?<sec>SEC.*?)\s' {
        $o[$Matches['sec']] = ($_ | ConvertFrom-StringData)[$Matches['sec']]
    }

    default {
        Write-Warning -Message "No match found: $_"
    }
}

# catch the last object
$output += [pscustomobject]$o

$output | Export-Csv -Path './some.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets leverage the strength of [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-6) which

> Converts a string containing one or more key and value pairs to a hash table.

So what we will do is

1. Split into blocks of text
2. edit the "; Key" line
3. Remove an blank lines or semicolon lines.
4. Pass to `ConvertFrom-StringData` to create a hashtable
5. Convert that to a PowerShell object

---

```
$path = "c:\temp\keys.txt"
# Split the file into its key/sec collections. Drop any black entries created in the split
(Get-Content -Raw $path) -split ";\s+KEY\s+" | Where-Object{-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)} | ForEach-Object{
    # Split the block into lines again
    $lines = $_ -split "`r`n" | Where-Object{$_ -notmatch "^;" -and -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)}
    # Edit the first line so we have a full block of key=value pairs.
    $lines[0] = "key=$($lines[0])"
    # Use ConvertFrom-StringData to do the leg work after we join the lines back as a single string.
    [pscustomobject](($lines -join "`r`n") | ConvertFrom-StringData)

} | 
    # Cannot guarentee column order so we force it with this select statement.
    Select-Object KEY,SEC1,SEC2,SEC3,SEC4,SEC5,SEC6
```

Use `Export-CSV` to your hearts content now.

Comment: Instead of removing fluff lines matching sec lines would word just as well. My approach converts the whole block into key value pairs so it can be processed in one shot

Comment: Looks like a lot of overhead, only to be able to use `ConvertFrom-StringData`. I don't see the benefit. Anyway, it works well, so +1